# Can others simply repost my Creative Commons YouTube video?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons, youtube

I posted a video on YouTube under the Creative Commons (CC) license. Some guy then simply reposts the entire video on his channel.

I file a copyright complaint, asking YouTube to take it down. But YouTube then rejects my request with this reply:

> By marking your video with a Creative Commons Attribution (CC-BY) licence, you granted members of the YouTube community an irrevocable licence to use your video. Although you may change the video licence at any time, any use of your video content while it was licensed as CC-BY will remain on the site, and we cannot honour your request to remove this video.

I thought the idea of CC was to encourage others to adapt and remix my content. Not simply copy it wholesale and just re-upload it to their channel.

So can others simply repost YouTube videos licensed under Creative Commons?

Comment: Note that there is not *the* Creative Commons license. There are many different ones. From the quoted message, it seems you were using "CC BY", but even then there are different versions of it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as long as they give you credit, the [Creative Commons - Attribution License (CC-BY)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) allows a person to:

> Share — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format
>
> Adapt — remix, transform, and build upon the material
>
> for any purpose, even commercially